# Generic type compatibility

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, variance, contravariance

I know this goes back to variance in general, but I am not sure how to resolve the issue shown below.
I want to have a list of generic sensors and add a specific sensor type to the list, but this generates a compiler error, basically stating that the type **TempHumSensor** is not compatible with **Sensor<Measurement>**

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    abstract class Measurement
    {
        public double Value { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    class TempHumMeasurement : Measurement 
    { 
        public double Temp { get; set; }
        public double Hum { get; set; }
        public TempHumMeasurement(double t, double h) 
        { 
            Value = t;
            Temp = t;
            Hum = h;
        }
    }

    abstract class Sensor<T> where T : Measurement
    {
        public List<T> Measurements = new();
    }

    class TempHumSensor : Sensor<TempHumMeasurement>
    {
        public TempHumSensor() { }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sensors = new List<Sensor<Measurement>>();
            var ths = new TempHumSensor();
            sensors.Add(ths);
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is with last line of code:

[compiler error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ycv0.png)

Why is that and how to put it the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this approach will help you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
   interface IMeasurement
    {
    double Value{get;set;}
    }

abstract class Measurement
{
    public double Value { get; set; } = 0;
}

class TempHumMeasurement : Measurement, IMeasurement 
{ 
    public double Temp { get; set; }
    public double Hum { get; set; }
    public TempHumMeasurement(double t, double h) 
    { 
        Value = t;
        Temp = t;
        Hum = h;
    }
}

abstract class Sensor<T> where T : IMeasurement
{
    public List<T> Measurements = new();
}

class TempHumSensor : Sensor<IMeasurement>
{
    public TempHumSensor() { }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sensors = new List<Sensor<IMeasurement>>();
        var ths = new TempHumSensor();
        sensors.Add(ths);           
    } 
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me check if that works. As the list is part of a REST API, I will need to check if JSON serialization is supported with interface types.

Comment: I have updated the code and using interfaces which resolves type compatibility. But then the next problem is that I am unable to deserialize interface types using HttpClient ReadFromJsonAsync<>(). Error message I get is "'Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'WebWeatherView.Shared.Interfaces.ISensor'. This is yet another problem I understand.